# Tensorboard Embeddings: "parsing metadata" hangs

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec, tensorboard

I am trying to visualize embeddings using tensorboard but the embedding tab seems to hang on "parsing metadata".

I checked the code, metadata tsv file, and the `projector_config.ptxt` against the [tensorboard embedding visualization tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/embedding_viz) ; everything seems to be correct and tensorboard is not giving me any messages in the terminal.

The code I am using to generate the embeddings and visualization can be found [here](https://github.com/chiphuyen/tf-stanford-tutorials/blob/master/examples/04_word2vec_visualize.py).

I am running tensorflow 1.2.1 for python 2.7 with gpu support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the [Tensorboard Embedding Visualization Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/embedding_viz#setup) is incorrect; the `metadata_path` property in `projector_config.pbtxt` needs to be set **relative** to the log directory. Otherwise, TensorBoard (the embedding projector frontend) will misleadingly halt at the "Parsing metadata" step as it searches for the metadata file in a path that does not exist.

For more on this, see the corresponding [issue on github.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/247)